# MongoDB can't find by national regex or query

Tags: java, mongodb, search

Looks like I miss something important. 
I have some records inserted into mongoDB that contains fields with national characters. There are no problem to insert it to DB or find them and all values looks pretty good. 
But if I try to find particular one with "find()" or "regex()" they return nothing. For example:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("position", Pattern.compile(".*forsøg.*"));
--or--
query.put("position","forsøg");
System.out.println(collection.find(query).count());  // prints 0
```

in log

```
query={ "position" : { "$regex" : ".*������.*"}}
--or---
query={ "position" : "������"}
```

Field value for "position" is equal "forsøg" ofc. Pattern.matches(".*forsøg.*", "forsøg") returns true.
If I replace pattern with one containing only ASCII characters (".*abc.*" for example  ) all methods work as expected. Collection.findAll() return all saved instances with readable and correct values.

Versions: MongoDB 2.0.6 64bit, mongo-java-driver 2.8.0, Java 7. I tried the same with spring-data-mongodb 1.0.2.RELEASE but removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I meet a strange bug related with a maven + testng. The same code executed from .war and from testsuit provides totally different result in database.

The difference may be easily found if point your browser to

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/baseName/collectionName/
```

and look at the values after each execution.

Comment: Are the saved results different in any explainable way .. for example UTF8 encoded versus not?  Perhaps there is an environment setting that differs in the test suite versus the deployed .war file.

Comment: Well, it turns out that there is a difference between calls made from 'mvn test' and 'mvn jetty:run'. I guess that surefire plugin ignores utf-8 settings.